# Print HTML Documents without popup in Android

Tags: android

I tried [this](https://developer.android.com/training/printing/html-docs.html) example & it is working fine.

But I don't want to see print popup.
Is it possible to prevent the print popup?

Answer (score 0):

Since `PrintManager` is final you can't override it's methods

But you can hide all System Dialogs using this

```
@Override
   public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    if (! hasFocus) {
        Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
        sendBroadcast(closeDialog);
    }
}
```

and If you want an example for Printing document you can refer to [Android-wifi-print](https://github.com/SureshCS-50/Android-wifi-print) - GitHub. This is just a prototype for printing document with the help of wifi printer.